# Implement a slider in Apps Script Web App. oninput event is not triggering

Tags: javascript, events, google-apps-script

I am trying to implement a slider that will display the current value while the user is moving the slider. I originally had an onchange event which displayed the value, but only once the user stopped dragging the slider. Once I changed it to oninput, the value never changes.

I have implemented this code outside of google apps script, and it works. Is there a way to get it to work within google apps script?

Here is the HTML Template:

```
<div id="min" style="display:inline">0</div>
<input type="range" id="slider" oninput="updateSliderValue()">
<div id="max" style="display:inline">100</div>
<div id="sliderValue">Current Value: 0</div>

<script>
function updateSliderValue(){
  var sliderValue = document.getElementById("slider").value;
  document.getElementById("sliderValue").innerHTML = "Current Value: " +    sliderValue;
}
</script>
```

And below is the simple code.gs:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('TestSliderTemplate').evaluate();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `doGet()` function to this:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('TestSliderTemplate')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
```

You need to set the `SandboxMode`.

Recently the only sandbox mode available changed to IFRAME.  The sandbox mode always defaults to IFRAME now.  Previously there were various sandbox modes starting with EMULATED, then it went to NATIVE, and now to IFRAME.  In the past you could choose between different modes, but now you can not.  But the IFRAME mode is the least restrictive, so it's much better.

[Google Documentation - SandBox Mode](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/sandbox-mode)

[Working HTML App of slider:](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbydaWqNllqJNJgpp0tduWBkYNsdutjFakxPHr7ZnS8pZRVEO4Z4/exec)

The File:

[Apps Script File](https://script.google.com/d/1GWyHsh1Sc53zVVX6eWGUdVqBcvZRnlTv2gghyWwdJ9cB4BHZQy-KQ1oh/edit?usp=sharing)